# p:commandLink does not work , when ajax rendered

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Im trying to build an ajax form. Im using bean variable called "pageMode", to hold the state of the form (start,confirm...etc). According to the value of pageMode, my jsf page renders or not render some buttons. (When start, only shows submit button, after submit shows confirm button...)

Here is my problem;

The Submit button works fine when i first visit the page, but Confirm button does not work properly (not fires bean method) after i submit means pageMode=confirm,

I tried to wrap my button with h:pannelGrid and put rendred attribute to it.. not worked :((.

xhtml looks like this;

```
<h:form id="ApplicationForm" styleClass ="form-horizontal well"> 

    <p:panel header="#{msg.bilgiler}" id="formVars"  styleClass="well">

    <h:panelGrid styleClass="defaultTable" id="pg" columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.ad}"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{applicationFormInc.userData.userName}" rendered="#{applicationFormInc.pageMode=='start'}"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{applicationFormInc.userData.userName}"  rendered="#{applicationFormInc.pageMode=='confirm'}"/>

        ...

        <p:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-primary" update="pg,confirmButtons" rendered="#{applicationFormInc.pageMode=='start'}"
                                   action="#{applicationFormInc.confirmActionAjax}" value="Submit">
                        <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
                    </p:commandLink>
        <h:panelGrid id="confirmButtons" >
        <p:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-primary" update="pg" rendered="#{applicationFormInc.pageMode=='confirm'}"
                       action="#{applicationFormInc.executeAction}" value="ConfirmAndSave" >
                        <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
                    </p:commandLink>

            </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>

</h:form>
```

Bean side executeAction

```
 public String executeAction(){
    DbTools tr = new DbTools();
    tr.insertRecord(getUserData()); 
    return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Thanx.

Comment: Can u post the `executeAction` code? or some part of it?

Comment: Added executeAction...

Answer (score 0):

define what you want to process with your commandLinks -

```
<p:commandLink .... process="ApplicationForm" >
```

or if you do not want to process any inputs:

```
<p:commandLink .... process="@this" >
```